# iwlist failed to read scan data when there are too many access point

Tags: networking, wireless, wireless-access-point

iwlist will return an error saying 'Failed to read scan data : Argument list too long' when there are around more than 130 access points and have a blank output. Is there a way to either increase the maximum number of arguments it can take or stop it at the 100th access point so that it wont reach its maximum and return error?

Comment: Can you not use iw instead?

Comment: Please try: `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: @RobertLongson I am interesting in extracting out the information of the access points, which is easier with iwlist format. I have look through iw format, although i am able to extract the same information, it is hard to differentiate between access points unlike how iwlist clear shows the cells number. Do you know how can i extract each access points information and save it as a list individually?

Comment: @chili555 thanks for the suggestion, will try that out! however I am more interested in 
 increasing the buffer size of the number of access points iwlist is able to "see". If im not wrong, the max count for it is at 128, but i need it to be able to see up to 200...